# Remove duplicate in list with regex and keep first

Tags: python, list

I have a python list such as

```
my_list = [
    'NIJG01002710.1_2-HSPs_-__Canis_lupus',
    'scaffold_313646_1-397_-__Homo_sapiens',
    'scaffold_366690_1-238_+__Homo_sapiens',
    'NIJG01003276.1_11652-11883_-__Cattus_cattus',
    'NIJG01006295.1_7474-7678_-__Cattus_cattus','YP_009353','NP_87899'
]
```

And I would like simply to keep the first duplicated value based on the element after the pattern `_-__` or `_+__`, here `Cattus_cattus` and `Homo_sapiens` are duplicated twice.

Here I should then get :

```
[
    'NIJG01002710.1_2-HSPs_-__Canis_lupus',
    'scaffold_313646_1-397_-__Homo_sapiens',
    'NIJG01003276.1_11652-11883_-__Cattus_cattus','YP_009353','NP_87899'
]
```

So far I know how to remove duplicate by using this code :

```
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(mylist))
```

but I do not known how to do it only using duplicate elements after a regex pattern.

One way would be to first remove everything before the pattern using :

```
my_list=[re.sub(r'*_?__', '', i) for i in x]
```

and then use:

```
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(mylist))
```

But in this way I loose the information before the pattenr that I need to keep.

Comment: And you expect us to code that for you? What did you try?

Comment: Hi, please add to your question what you have tried so far

Comment: So far I know how to remove duplicate by using this code :

   ``` mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(mylist))```

but I do not known how to do it only using duplicate elements after a regex pattern.

Comment: Please add it to your question. And please attempt it with a regex yourself, and then we will be able to help

Comment: I added the solution but as I say in the post this one does not keep all the element name as I would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_list = [
    'NIJG01002710.1_2-HSPs_-__Canis_lupus',
    'scaffold_313646_1-397_-__Homo_sapiens',
    'scaffold_366690_1-238_+__Homo_sapiens',
    'NIJG01003276.1_11652-11883_-__Cattus_cattus',
    'NIJG01006295.1_7474-7678_-__Cattus_cattus']


print([f'{value}__{key}' for key, value in
       dict(item.split('__')[::-1] for item in 
       my_list[::-1]).items()][::-1])
```

output

```
['NIJG01002710.1_2-HSPs_-__Canis_lupus',
 'scaffold_313646_1-397_-__Homo_sapiens',
 'NIJG01003276.1_11652-11883_-__Cattus_cattus']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split on multiple delimiters with `re.split()`, which isn't even necessary here, as you could just split on `__`, anyhow:

```
import re
p = ['_-__', '_\+__']

list({re.split('|'.join(p), s)[-1]:s for s in my_list[::-1]}.values())[::-1]

# ['NIJG01002710.1_2-HSPs_-__Canis_lupus', 'scaffold_313646_1-397_-__Homo_sapiens', 'NIJG01003276.1_11652-11883_-__Cattus_cattus']
```

---

Without regex at all:

```
list({s.rsplit('__', 1)[-1]: s for s in my_list[::-1]}.values())[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve this is to iterate over the list and use a second list to store the elements we have seen previously.

```
import re
pattern = r'(?<=_[\+-]__)(.*)'

found = []
result = []

for i in my_list:
    if (match := re.search(pattern, i).group()) not in found:
        result.append(i)
        found.append(match)
```

Outputs

```
found
#['Canis_lupus', 'Homo_sapiens', 'Cattus_cattus']

result
#['NIJG01002710.1_2-HSPs_-__Canis_lupus', 'scaffold_313646_1-397_-__Homo_sapiens', 'NIJG01003276.1_11652-11883_-__Cattus_cattus']
```